# WCF SwaggerWCF implementation

Tags: c#, wcf, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-wcf

I m setting up a WCF service and i want to implement SwaggerWCF for the documantation.

i configured like [SwaggerWCF](https://github.com/abelsilva/swaggerwcf#self-hosted) docs. But when i want to access doc  as http://localhost/RegistrationService/api-docs, it redirects me to http://localhost/RegistrationService/api-docs/index.html?url=/RegistrationService/api-docs/swagger.json . and it is giving 404.0 error.

I added Swagger Attributes in my Model and methods.In the following I am sharing my configuration.

**My app.config**

```
<configSections>
    <section name="swaggerwcf" type="SwaggerWcf.Configuration.SwaggerWcfSection, SwaggerWcf" />
  </configSections>
  <swaggerwcf>
    <tags>
      <tag name="LowPerformance" visible="false" />
    </tags>
    <settings>
      <setting name="InfoDescription" value="Sample Service to test SwaggerWCF" />
      <setting name="InfoVersion" value="0.0.1" />
      <setting name="InfoTermsOfService" value="Terms of Service" />
      <setting name="InfoTitle" value="SampleService" />
      <setting name="InfoContactName" value="Abel Silva" />
      <setting name="InfoContactUrl" value="http://github.com/abelsilva" />
      <setting name="InfoContactEmail" value="no@e.mail" />
      <setting name="InfoLicenseUrl" value="https://github.com/abelsilva/SwaggerWCF/blob/master/LICENSE" />
      <setting name="InfoLicenseName" value="Apache License" />
    </settings>
  </swaggerwcf>
```

**Global Asax**

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("api-docs", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(SwaggerWcfEndpoint)));
        }
```

Why am i getting 404 error?

Answer (score 1):

I mean you have a service DummyService, where is the endpoint configuration for that service? I only see your endpoint for SwaggerWcf.ISwaggerWcfEndpoint.

And you should modify your  configuration according to your rest service.

Below is my modified configuration.

Service Interface. Please pay attention to my SwaggerWcfPath,it is books corresponding to the webget uritemplate ""/books?filter={filtername}""

```
namespace ServiceInterface
{

[ServiceContract]
 public interface IStore
{


    [SwaggerWcfPath("/books", "Retrieve all books from the store")]

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/books?filter={filtername}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]

   // [OperationContract]

    Book[] ReadBooks(string filtername=null);


}
}
```

MyService  SwaggerWcf's parameter is the name of your svc, mine is Store.svc

```
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =   AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
   [SwaggerWcf("Store.svc")]
public class BookStore : IStore
{
       [SwaggerWcfTag("Books")]

    [SwaggerWcfResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Book found, value in the response body")]

   [SwaggerWcfResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "No books", true)]

    public Book[] ReadBooks(string filtername=null)

    {

        WebOperationContext woc = WebOperationContext.Current;



        if (woc == null)

            return null;



        if (Store.Books.Any())

        {

            woc.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(filtername)

                ? Store.Books.ToArray()

                : Store.Books.Where(b => b.Author.Name.Contains(filtername) || b.Title.Contains(filtername)).ToArray();

        }



        woc.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

        return Store.Books.ToArray();

    }
}
```

My web.config. Service.BookStore is the service which is activated through Store.svc(parameter of SwaggerWcf)

```
 <service name="SwaggerWcf.SwaggerWcfEndpoint">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SwaggerWcf.ISwaggerWcfEndpoint"></endpoint>
  </service>


<service name="Service.BookStore">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ServiceInterface.IStore" behaviorConfiguration="web" ></endpoint>
 <endpointBehaviors>

    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

Comment: Could you please share your project source code? I want to try your code.

Comment: Hi, I have published my project to github. The address is [https://github.com/luanmafeng/WcfSwaggerStart](https://github.com/luanmafeng/WcfSwaggerStart)

Comment: Yes your project is working. i will check. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration of RouteTable.Routes is api-docs, you should set it to "RegistrationService/api-docs".

My Application_Start

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("RegistrationService/api-docs", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(SwaggerWcfEndpoint)));
```

My web.config.

```
 <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

```
 <service name="SwaggerWcf.SwaggerWcfEndpoint">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"      contract="SwaggerWcf.ISwaggerWcfEndpoint"></endpoint>
  </service>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

My Contract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IStore
{


    [SwaggerWcfPath("Get books", "Retrieve all books from the store")]

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/books?filter={filterText}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]

    [OperationContract]

    Book[] ReadBooks(string filterText = null);


}
```

My service.

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[SwaggerWcf("/v1/rest")]
public class BookStore : IStore
{

    [SwaggerWcfTag("Books")]

    [SwaggerWcfResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Book found, value in the response body")]

    [SwaggerWcfResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "No books", true)]

    public Book[] ReadBooks(string filterText = null)

    {

        WebOperationContext woc = WebOperationContext.Current;



        if (woc == null)

            return null;



        if (Store.Books.Any())

        {

            woc.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterText)

                ? Store.Books.ToArray()

                : Store.Books.Where(b => b.Author.Name.Contains(filterText) || b.Title.Contains(filterText)).ToArray();

        }



        woc.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

        return Store.Books.ToArray();

    }
}
```

The result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

add the decorator for the call path in the service

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[SwaggerWcf("/api")]
```

"/api" replace the correct name